# Use excanvas together with kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, excanvas, kineticjs

I've tried to use excanvas.js together with kinetic.js, but with no success.

Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to be trying to do the same with fxcanvas (http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/) at some point soon and will update this thread if that turns out to be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after modifying the code of kinetic.js I was able to run it in IE6.
But since excanvas has no isPointInPath function, which is needed in kinetic.js, it's not possible to get events to work. Unless someone implements this function for excanvas.

Comment: did you ever figure out an answer to this? different canvas library?

Comment: Guys, like I already said, it's not possible to make it work, because there is functionality missing in excanvas that is needed to run kinetic.js. Downvotes are really not necessary.